# Set DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueMember to an other column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with to DataSources. One DataSource for one ComboBoxColumn and one for the whole DataGridView.

How can I display the right text for my DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dependig on an ID which is set with the "main" DataSource?

```
this.dgvFeinfilter.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
this.dgvFeinfilter.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFFZNr = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colFFZNr.Name = this.ffznr;
colFFZNr.DataPropertyName = this.ffznr;
colFFZNr.Visible = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFFFnr = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colFFFnr.Name = this.fffnr;
colFFFnr.DataPropertyName = this.fffnr;
colFFFnr.Visible = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFFnr = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colFFnr.Name = this.ffnr;
colFFnr.DataPropertyName = this.ffnr;
colFFnr.Visible = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFFPosition = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colFFPosition.Name = this.ffPosition;
colFFPosition.HeaderText = this.headerReihenfolge;
colFFPosition.DataPropertyName = this.ffPosition;
colFFPosition.Visible = true;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colFeinfilter = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
colFeinfilter.DataSource = this.DsView.Tables["Feinfilter"];
colFeinfilter.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
colFeinfilter.HeaderText = this.headerFeinfilter;
colFeinfilter.DataPropertyName = this.ffKennung; //this.ffnr;
colFeinfilter.DisplayMember = this.ffKennung;
colFeinfilter.ValueMember = this.ffnr;
colFeinfilter.Name = this.ffKennung;
colFeinfilter.Width = 300;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colDelete = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colDelete.Name = "MarkForDelete";
colDelete.Visible = false;
colDelete.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = 0;

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from zuordnung in this.DsWork.Tables["FFZuordnung"].AsEnumerable()
                                         where zuordnung.Field<Decimal>(this.fffnr) == this.feinfilterfolge.FFFNr
                                         select zuordnung;

DataView newView = query.AsDataView();
this.dgvFeinfilter.DataSource = newView;
this.dgvFeinfilter.Columns.AddRange(colFFPosition, colFeinfilter, colFFZNr, colFFFnr, colFFnr, colDelete);
```

DataSource 1 (this.DsView.Tables["Feinfilter"]):

```
SELECT
    FFSPNR,    -- id
    FFKENNUNG  -- name
FROM
    Feinfilter
WHERE
    FFKENNUNG IS NOT NULL
```

DataSource 2 (this.DsWork.Tables["FFZuordnung"]):

```
SELECT
    FFZLFDNR,        --id
    FFSPNR,          --fk
    FFFNr,           --fk
    FFZREIHENFOLGE,  --number
    TSUPDATE         --datetime
FROM
    FFZUORDNUNG
```

After binding all (also the invisible) Columns has the right value. Unless the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. The value is empty. If I change the `colFeinfilter.DataPropertyName = this.ffKennung;` to `colFeinfilter.DataPropertyName = this.ffnr;` then the right ID is displayed. But I need the "ffKennung".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
colFeinfilter.DataPropertyName = this.ffnr;
colFeinfilter.DisplayMember = this.ffKennung;
```

Value of `DataPropertyName` will define which value must be selected
Value of `DisplayMember` will be used to display text for selected value